# Displaying arrays of sprites in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I have created an array of Vector2 which holds the position of the place where the sprite will be displayed:
    Vector2[,] SpritePosition = new Vector2[4,4];

Then I wrote a for loop to intialize the position of each member:

```
public void loadArray()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                SpritePosition[i, j] = new Vector2(i*texture.Width , j*texture.Width);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have created a texture which holds a sprite and the next position is calculated according to the width needed for the image in the texture(One image is being loaded in 4 rows of 4).

Then I used the following code in the Draw() function

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                spriteBatch.Draw(texture, SpritePosition[i,j], Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

But when I run the program, its showing me only 1 image, not a 4 rows of 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, But for one thing. 
I think you meant `SpritePosition[i, j] = new Vector2(i*texture.Width , j*texture.Height);`
(height the second time, not width)

And I see no need for an array here why not just

`spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(i*texture.Width,j*texture.Height), Color.White);`

Also, this is not a "code for you" site. I see you just posted this question right After I answered your last. Seemingly it dosen't seem you looked into trying to figure it out yourself to much.

Comment: Ya, I meant height. And yes, I will keep that in mind. Its just that I am beginning game programming and a lot of difficulties come up way tooo fast

Comment: it worked. And I don't mean to use this as a code for you site. I am sorry if it seems so

Comment: Glad to see it works, and Okay. Offtopic: You asked the 3000th XNA question!